# background of terminator is not set properly

Tags: desktop-background, terminator

I have installed terminator and it is working fine but there is one problem with the setting of background.

The background doesn't cover the full image rather only a part of the image is set as the background. While for some images, the background is in the form of tiles.

- terminator background:

  [image: terminator background]
- actual picture:

  [image: actual picture]

It will be really helpful is somebody can suggest a solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Terminator doesn't have a feature to scale or adjust background images. Your only option is to resize or otherwise adjust the size of the background image with an image processor.